# Getting a warning C4189 "local variable is initialized but not referenced" even though the variable is being referenced

Tags: c++, qt

I have a piece of C++ code using Qt where I try to run a batch file in the command prompt. I use a `QProcess` object to start `cmd.exe` and execute my batch file. Below is the code I'm using:

```
void Utility::executeBatchFile(QString batchFile)
{
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    QString cmdName = "cmd.exe";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments<<"/k" << batchFile;
    process->startDetached(cmdName, arguments);
}
```

When I build it in Qt Creator, I get a warning:

> warning: C4189: 'process' : local variable is initialized but not referenced

The variable `process` is referenced in the last line of the function, and I'm unable to figure out why exactly this warning appears.

Comment: And you are leaking `process`, too...

Comment: Oh, yes!! Thanks for pointing that out! I had totally forgotten the delete. Anyway, it looks like I can directly call QProcess::startDetached() instead of having to create an object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because `startDetached` is a static member function. You're allowed to write `process->startDetached(...)` in order to indicate the namespace in which the compiler will look for the member name, instead of `QProcess::startDetached(...)`. But the two invocations are identical; the call does not use the value of `process`.

Comment: This also helped me. Same warning (C4189) started to show up when I upgraded the compiler from MSVC2010 to MSVC2013.

Comment: A year and a half later, and this has saved the day. Many thanks!